# IndexedDB not creating a new object store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

I am using [react-indexed-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-indexed-db) library for handling browser indexedDB for storing some datas.

First i published my website with one object store:-
src/config/DBConfig.js

```
export const DBConfig = {
  name: "bookDB",
  version: 1,
  objectStoresMeta: [
    {
      store: "reads",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "hash", autoIncrement: false },
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "hash", keypath: "hash", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "token", keypath: "token", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "sa", keypath: "sa", options: { unique: false } },
        { name: "ss", keypath: "ss", options: { unique: false } },
      ],
    }
  ],
};
```

And today i've added new object store to the same DB :-

```
export const DBConfig = {
  name: "bookDB",
  version: 1,
  objectStoresMeta: [
    {
      store: "reads",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "hash", autoIncrement: false },
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "hash", keypath: "hash", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "token", keypath: "token", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "sa", keypath: "sa", options: { unique: false } },
        { name: "ss", keypath: "ss", options: { unique: false } },
      ],
    },
    {
      store: "books",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "hash", autoIncrement: false },
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "hash", keypath: "hash", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "token", keypath: "token", options: { unique: true } },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Example file of how i am calling both db objects:-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { initDB, useIndexedDB } from "react-indexed-db";
import { DBConfig } from "../config/DBConfig";

initDB(DBConfig);

const BookRead = (props) => {
  const readsObject = useIndexedDB("reads");
  const booksObject = useIndexedDB("books");

  const [storedRead, setStoredRead] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    readsObject
      .getByIndex("hash", props.match.params.id)
      .then((data) => {
        setStoredRead(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {});
  }, []);

  const readRequest = (token) => {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}book/read`, {
        name: readerName(),
        token: token,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.token) {
          booksObject.add({
            hash: props.match.params.id,
            token: res.data.token,
          });

          readsObject.add({
            hash: props.match.params.id,
            token: res.data.token,
            ss: "",
            sa: "",
          });
        } else {
          setData(res.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return <div>Book Content</div>;
};

export default BookRead;
```

Now, in some browsers i can see the new object store "books" is created while in some not created.

Is is related to indexedDB schema version ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is similar to existing questions, readily answered within moments of reading introductory documentation, is unlikely to help others, and because it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing version from 1 to 2 :-

```
export const DBConfig = {
  name: "bookDB",
  version: 2,
  objectStoresMeta: [
    {
      store: "reads",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "hash", autoIncrement: false },
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "hash", keypath: "hash", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "token", keypath: "token", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "sa", keypath: "sa", options: { unique: false } },
        { name: "ss", keypath: "ss", options: { unique: false } },
      ],
    },
    {
      store: "books",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "hash", autoIncrement: false },
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "hash", keypath: "hash", options: { unique: true } },
        { name: "token", keypath: "token", options: { unique: true } },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```